# How to calculate totalPrice in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, many-to-many, virtual-functions

I have four tables: Users, Orders, OrderProducts (join table), and Products.

I want to calculate `totalprice` column in Orders table. OrderProducts has `quantity` and `productId`, Products has `price` column.

Do I need to add `price` column in OrderProducts table for each item `(price * quantity)`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to add a price column in the OrderProducts table. You can achieve this by creating a Sequelize association between the tables and using Sequelize's aggregation functions.

```
Orders.hasMany(OrderProducts);
OrderProducts.belongsTo(Products);
```

Now, you can calculate the total price dynamically during queries based on the associated data by using the Sequelize's ***SUM*** function to multiply the quantity from OrderProducts with the price from Products, resulting in the total price for each order :

```
const ordersWithTotalPrice = await Orders.findAll({
attributes: [
    'id',
    [sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.literal('`OrderProducts`.`quantity` * `Products`.`price`')), 'totalPrice']
],
include: [
    {
        model: OrderProducts,
        attributes: [],
        include: [
            {
                model: Products,
                attributes: []
            }
        ]
    }
],
group: ['Orders.id']
});

console.log(ordersWithTotalPrice);
```

It is equivalent to executing the following SQL querie:

```
SELECT 
Orders.id,
SUM(OrderProducts.quantity * Products.price) AS totalPrice
FROM 
Orders
JOIN 
OrderProducts ON Orders.id = OrderProducts.OrderId
JOIN 
Products ON OrderProducts.ProductId = Products.id
GROUP BY 
Orders.id;
```

This approach ensures that the totalPrice column in the Orders table stays up-to-date without the need for redundant data storage.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to add a `price` column to the `OrderProducts` table. Instead, you can calculate the total price when needed by joining the necessary tables in a query. Here's a general approach:

1. **Database Schema:**

- Users (UserId, UserName, ...)
- Orders (OrderId, UserId, TotalPrice, ...)
- OrderProducts (Id, OrderId, ProductId, Quantity, ...)
- Products (ProductId, Price, ...)

2. **Query to Calculate Total Price:**
   You can use a query to calculate the total price by joining the `Orders`, OrderProducts, and Products tables:

```sql
SELECT
    O.OrderId,
    O.UserId,
    SUM(OP.Quantity * P.Price) AS TotalPrice
FROM
    Orders O
    JOIN OrderProducts OP ON O.OrderId = OP.OrderId
    JOIN Products P ON OP.ProductId = P.ProductId
GROUP BY
    O.OrderId, O.UserId;
```

In this query, `SUM(OP.Quantity * P.Price)` calculates the total price for each order by multiplying the quantity from `OrderProducts` with the corresponding product price from the `Products` table.

By organizing your data this way, you avoid redundancy and ensure that the total price is always calculated based on the current product prices. If the price of a product changes, the total price for historical orders will still reflect the correct value.

3. **Updating Total Price in Orders Table:**
   If you want to store the total price in the `Orders` table for quick retrieval, you can update it using the calculated values:

```sql
UPDATE Orders O
SET TotalPrice = (
    SELECT SUM(OP.Quantity * P.Price)
    FROM OrderProducts OP
        JOIN Products P ON OP.ProductId = P.ProductId
    WHERE O.OrderId = OP.OrderId
);
```

This query updates the `TotalPrice` column in the `Orders` table for each order based on the calculated sum.

Remember to adjust the column and table names according to your actual database schema. Adding a `TotalPrice` column in the `Orders` table is a common practice to improve query performance when you frequently need to retrieve the total price without recalculating it every time.